# What is the type of a "variable" containing a lambda function that captures by reference?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I was doing a quick experiment with lambda functions and I'm having trouble figuring out how to declare the `testFunc` variable below.

Generally speaking, a function pointer can be defined as follows:

```
int (*someFunc)(int, int) = otherFunction;
```

When doing this for a lambda function without any closures, it works fine:

```
int (*someFunc)(int) = [](int a) -> int { return 0; };
```

However, I get a compiler error when trying to capture by reference:

```
void (*testFunc)() = [&]() -> void { /* code here */ };
```

It works if I declare `testfunc` as `auto` instead, but I'm curious what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: you can use `std::function<void()>` but should be aware of overhead, it is pretty small but exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

All lambdas have unique anonymous types. (that's why `auto` works)

Lambdas without captures are convertible to function pointers, but capturing lambdas are not.

Comment: Excellent answer! Could you give an example definition of a variable containing a lambda with a capture closure? I'm guessing it requires a template class?

Comment: @Gogeta70 I'm not sure what you mean by 'capture closure'.

Comment: I mean how would I define `testFunc` above in my question?

Comment: @Gogeta70 It is not possible without `auto`. Lambdas capturing state can not be converted to regular function pointer.

Comment: Lambda types are called anonymous for a reason. :)

Comment: You can assign them to `std::function` though